# When scroll up & down list row associated views get changed

Tags: android, android-widget

I made a custom list of categories. Some categories have nested categories.

When the list contains up to 9 rows (the visible area can contain 9 rows without scrolling) the code works well, but when I add the 10th row (here the list becomes scrollable) and scroll down the list, the row appearance will change.

This happens with rows containing nested lists (they have "move next image"). When I scroll down and back up, rows having "move next image" disappear.

The custom adapter I use is:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        View rowView = convertView;

        if (rowView == null)
        {
          LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
          rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.m_category_list_activity, null);

          ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

          viewHolder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
          viewHolder.image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

          rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();

        holder.text.setText(values.get(position));

        String s = status.get(position);

        if (s.equals("s")) 
        {
            holder.image.setVisibility(IGNORE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE);
        } 

        return rowView;
     }
```

I don't understand what the problem is. I am even using convertView.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (s.equals("s")) 
    {
        holder.image.setVisibility(IGNORE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE);
    }
```

I think that you are missing the "else" clause (reset to default) and that's why recycling fails. Remember that when you are recycling views you will get it exactly as the last item left it, so you need to set all of the view properties you care for again.

Answer (score 0):

Change your getView() method to this, It will work for you

```
@Override

 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
  {
    View rowView = convertView;

    if (rowView == null)
    {
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.m_category_list_activity, null);

      ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

      viewHolder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
      viewHolder.image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

      rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
       rowView.getTag(viewHolder);
    }

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();

    holder.text.setText(values.get(position));

    String s = status.get(position);

    if (s.equals("s")) 
    {
        holder.image.setVisibility(IGNORE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE);
    } 

    return rowView;
 }
```